# golang why named and non-named struct comparison with equal result

Tags: go, struct, types, comparison

The Go Programming Language [Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) said.

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

But as following code snippet, it seems variable v1, and v3 has different type, why they can get a true output:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type T1 struct { name string }
type T2 struct { name string }

func main() {
    v1 := T1 { "foo" }
    v2 := T2 { "foo" }
    v3 := struct{ name string } {"foo"}
    v4 := struct{ name string } {"foo"}

    fmt.Println("v1: type=", reflect.TypeOf(v1), "value=", reflect.ValueOf(v1)) // v1: type= main.T1 value= {foo}
    fmt.Println("v2: type=", reflect.TypeOf(v2), "value=", reflect.ValueOf(v2)) // v2: type= main.T2 value= {foo}
    fmt.Println("v3: type=", reflect.TypeOf(v3), "value=", reflect.ValueOf(v3)) // v3: type= struct { name string } value= {foo}
    fmt.Println("v4: type=", reflect.TypeOf(v4), "value=", reflect.ValueOf(v4)) // v4: type= struct { name string } value= {foo}

    //fmt.Println(v1 == v2) // compiler error: invalid operation: v1 == v2 (mismatched types T1 and T2)
    fmt.Println(v1 == v3)   // true, why? their type is different
    fmt.Println(v2 == v3)   // true, why?
    fmt.Println(v3 == v4)   // true
}
```

It's reasonable that `v1 == v2` fails with compile error because they are different type, however how to explain the `v1 == v3` get a `true` result, since they also have different types, one with named struct type `T1`, and the other with anonymous struct.
Thanks.

### Update Question based on feedback

Thanks @icza, @John Weldon for your explanation, I think this issue is resolved, I am now updating the question.

In summary, a struct is comparable if it meet following 2 specs:

> 1. Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.
> 2. In any comparison, the first operand must be assignable to the type of the second operand, or vice versa.

The 1st one is for struct type variable specific; and the 2nd one is for all types variable comparison, struct type variable is covered of course.

In my sample, the comparison variable v1 and v3 meet these two specs definition.

1. All fields are comparable; in fact, the first spec define the struct rule, it focus on fields, but not struct itself, so whatever a named struct or anonymous struct, they are same rule.
2. Variable v1 and v3 is assignable. (according to the rule: x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type)

So this is to explain why "v1 == v3" can get a true result.
Thanks all.

Comment: I'm go expert (hence a comment), but I would guess that structs behave similar to strings in that they are untyped until they are required. That is, comparing some string constant to a named string type will work, but comparing two named string types will raise a compiler error. This would be caused by go being very type strict and hence sees 2 "different" named types and hence raises the error. Again, I'm only just learning go myself so could be way off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read that spec carefully, you can see that if the corresponding non-blank fields are equal then the two structs are equal.  If the type *name* is different the compiler will fail, but if one or both of the types are anonymous then they'll be comparable. The types `T1` or `T2`, and the anonymous structs are effectively the same type because they have the same fields.  When the field values are the same then they compare as the same.

Looking at [type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) in the spec may (or may not, ymmv) make it clearer.

> Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical types, and identical tags. Non-exported field names from different packages are always different.

So, if you try the same experiment but change the types by adding field tags, or by putting the types in different packages, you may get the differences you expect.

Comment: You stated that the structs would be comparable "Even if the type names are different", could you explain why OP got a compiler error for `v1 == v2` please?

Comment: Good catch @mattjegan - my error.  Updated the wording.

Answer (score 2):

What you miss is that the (equality) comparison operator does not require its operands to be of the same type. The requirement is according to the [Spec: Comparison operators:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators)

> In any comparison, the first operand must be [**assignable**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to the type of the second operand, or vice versa.

Yes, type equality automatically gives the assignability attribute, but there are other cases:

> A value `x` is assignable to a variable of type `T` ("`x` is assignable to `T`") in any of these cases:
>
> - `x`'s type is identical to `T`.
> - **`x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical [underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions) type.**
> - `T` is an interface type and `x` [implements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types) `T`.
> - `x` is a bidirectional channel value, `T` is a channel type, `x`'s type `V` and `T` have identical element types, and at least one of `V` or `T` is not a defined type.
> - `x` is the predeclared identifier `nil` and `T` is a pointer, function, slice, map, channel, or interface type.
> - `x` is an untyped [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) representable by a value of type `T`.

The highlighted rule applies here. `v1`, `v2` and `v3` all have the same underlying type (which is `struct { name string }`), and in the `v1 == v3` and `v2 == v3` comparisons only `v1`'s type is [defined](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions). So they are assignable, and from there, the comparison rule that applies to `struct` values you quoted clearly explains why the result is `true`:

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

There's nothing "shocking" about this if you think about it. You're not comparing the types, you're comparing the values. What may not be intuitive is when the comparison may be used, but the rules are listed clearly and cleanly at assignability.

Another similar example (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vb1YJZMKed)):

```
var i interface{} = 3
var j int = 3
fmt.Println(i == j) // Comparing interface{} with int: true
```

We're comparing values of `interface{}` and `int` types (even more "distant" that your struct types), yet this is valid and the result is `true` and there's nothing shocking about that either, on the contrary, we'd expect that. `int` is assignable to a variable of type `interface{}` (everything is assignable to `interface{}`). When comparing them, an implicit `interface{}` value will be created that wraps `j`, and those 2 interface values will be compared according to this rule:

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value `nil`.

**Notes:**

Assignability is a *requirement* but not a *satisfactory* condition to comparability. Further requirements are outlined in the [Spec: Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) that also must be met, based on the types of the operands:

> The equality operators `==` and `!=` apply to operands that are *comparable*. The ordering operators `<`, `<=`, `>`, and `>=` apply to operands that are *ordered*. These terms and the result of the comparisons are defined as follows:
>
> - Boolean values are comparable. Two boolean values are equal if they are either both `true` or both `false`.
> - Integer values are comparable and ordered, in the usual way.
> - Floating-point values are comparable and ordered, as defined by the IEEE-754 standard.
> - Complex values are comparable. Two complex values `u` and `v` are equal if both `real(u) == real(v)` and `imag(u) == imag(v)`.
> - String values are comparable and ordered, lexically byte-wise.
> - Pointer values are comparable. Two pointer values are equal if they point to the same variable or if both have value `nil`. Pointers to distinct [zero-size](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees) variables may or may not be equal.
> - Channel values are comparable. Two channel values are equal if they were created by the same call to [make](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) or if both have value `nil`.
> - Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have [identical](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value `nil`.
> - A value `x` of non-interface type `X` and a value `t` of interface type `T` are comparable when values of type `X` are comparable and `X` implements `T`. They are equal if `t`'s dynamic type is identical to `X` and `t`'s dynamic value is equal to `x`.
> - Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-[blank](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) fields are equal.
> - Array values are comparable if values of the array element type are comparable. Two array values are equal if their corresponding elements are equal.
>
> A comparison of two interface values with identical dynamic types causes a [run-time panic](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Run_time_panics) if values of that type are not comparable. This behavior applies not only to direct interface value comparisons but also when comparing arrays of interface values or structs with interface-valued fields.
>
> Slice, map, and function values are not comparable. However, as a special case, a slice, map, or function value may be compared to the predeclared identifier `nil`. Comparison of pointer, channel, and interface values to nil is also allowed and follows from the general rules above.

As a trivial example the spec explicitly states slice values are not comparable:

```
i1, i2 := []int{1, 2}, []int{1, 2}
fmt.Println(i1 == i2)
// invalid operation: i1 == i2 (slice can only be compared to nil)
```

Even though `i1` and `i2` have identical types, and therefore `i1` is assignable to `i2` (and vice versa), comparison is still not allowed and therefore they are not comparable.

Another less trivial example is that structs *may* be comparable *if* all their fields are comparable. So for example values of this struct are **not** comparable (because it has a field of slice type and slices are not comparable):

```
type Foo struct { Names []string }
```

Comment: i am still confuse the spec "In any comparison, the first operand must be assignable to the type of the second operand, or vice versa."; based on my understand, that if variable v1 and v2 is comparable, it means v1 is assignable to v2 or v2 is assignable to v1, but it does not mean "if v1 is assignable to v2, or vice verse, v1 and v2 is comparable". so assignable is a necessary condition for comparable, not a sufficient condition for comparable. is this true ? thx

Comment: @Hui Your understanding is correct. See edited answer with example.

Comment: with your nice explanation, i think i has understand the issue, i will update my question.